# The Include path expression must refer to a navigation property defined on the type (select data using LINQ)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I was trying to select data using LINQ
and I have a list called "products" and I want just these items that exist in products list

```cs
var Owner = db.Owners
  .Where(m => m.ID == id)
  .Include(m => m.Products.Where(item1 => products.Any(item2 => item2.ProductID == item1.ProductID)).ToList())
  .FirstOrDefault();
```

**but I'm getting this error :**

> System.ArgumentException: 'The Include path expression must refer to a navigation property defined on the type. Use dotted paths for reference navigation properties and the Select operator for collection navigation properties.
> Parameter name: path'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include is meant to fetch complete rows of a table, inclusive primary and foreign keys.

Usually it is not efficient to fetch the complete rows of a table. For example, suppose you have a database with Schools and Students. There is a one-to-many relation between Schools and Students: every School has zero or more Students, every Student attends exactly one School, namely the School that the foreign key refers to.

If you fetch School [10] with its 2000 Students, then every Student will have a foreign key SchoolId with a value 10. If you use Include and fetch complete Student rows you will transfer this value 10 over 2000 times. What a waste of processing power!

A DbContext has a ChangeTracker object. Whenever you fetch data without using Select, so if you fetch complete rows, then the fetched rows are stored in the ChangeTracker, together with a Clone of it. You get a reference to the Clone (or the original, doesn't matter). When you change properties of the fetched data, you change the value in the Clone. When you call `SaveChanges`, the values of all properties of all originals in the ChangeTracker are compared with the values in the Clones. The items that are changed are updated in the database.

So if you fetch School [10] with its 2000 Students, you are not only fetching way more data than you will ever use, but you will also store all these Students in the ChangeTracker together with a Cloned Student. If you call SaveChanges for something completely different (change of the telephone number of the School for instance), then all Students are compared by value property by property with their Clones.

Generic rule:

> Whenever you fetch data using Entity Framework, always use `Select`, and Select only the properties that you actually plan to use. Only fetch complete rows and only use Include if you plan to update the fetched data.

Using Select will also solve your problem:

```
int ownerId = ...
IEnumerable<Product> products = ...

var Owner = db.Owners.Where(owner => owner.ID == ownerId)
    .Select(owner => new
    {
        // Select only the Owner properties that you actually plan to use
        Id = owner.Id,
        Name = owner.Name,

        // get the Products of this Owner that are in variable products
        Products = owner.Products
            .Where(product => products.Any(p => p.ProductId == product.ProductId)
            .Select(product => new
            {
                // Select only the Product properties that you plan to use
                Id = product.Id,
                Price = product.Price,
                ...

                // No need to fetch the foreign key, you already fetched the value
                // OwnerId = product.OwnerId,
            })
            .ToList(),
        ...
    })
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

I used automatic types (`new {...}`). If you really want to create Owner and Properties, use:

```
var Owner = db.Owners.Where(...)
.Select(owner => new Owner
{
    Id = owner.Id,
    ...

    Products = owner.Products.Where(...).Select(product => new Product
    {
        Id = product.Id,
        ...
    })
    .ToList(),
})
.FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score -2):

Try the following:

```cs
var productIds = products.Select(x => x.ProductID);

var Owner = db.Owners
  .Where(m => m.ID == id)
  .Include(m => m.Products.Where(product => productIds.Contains(product.ProductID))
  .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: You, much like OP, seem to be under the impression that `Include` does anything (in your case, you seem to believe it filters?). That is indeed not the case, `Include`, like `GC.KeepAlive()` for example, simply references a field for the sake of referencing it. In EF's case, you use `Include` to reference foreign tables you want to select along with the rest of your query. There is absolutely no filtering involved in this.

Comment: @Blindy, Actually no, I'm very experienced in LINQ to Entities. OP is trying to filter out related entities, this is simplest way.

Comment: I'm sure you are very experienced indeed, but `Include` **does not filter anything**.

Comment: @Blindy, yes I'm sure [Filtered Include](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/eager#filtered-include)

Comment: You said LINQ to Entities, not EF.Core.

Comment: @Blindy, do you think it is not EF Core?